# Ruby selenium cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, eclipse, selenium, browserstack

I'm trying to utilize BrowserStack's automated testing using ruby with Selenium WebDriver with Eclipse.

Here is the code i'm trying to run:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

# Input capabilities
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
caps["browser"] = "IE"
caps["browser_version"] = "7.0"
caps["os"] = "Windows"
caps["os_version"] = "XP"
caps["browserstack.debug"] = "true"
caps[:name] = "Testing Selenium 2 with Ruby on BrowserStack"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote,
  :url => "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub",
  :desired_capabilities => caps)
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com/ncr"
element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "BrowserStack"
element.submit
puts driver.title

driver.quit
```

And here is the error i'm running into:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/user/Documents/workspace/Lowfares/ie/wintest.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have the `selenium-webdriver` gem installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I realized is when you install selenium you need to run `sudo gem install selenium-webdriver` for applications to access it.

Answer (score 8):

In my case it helped to add the following to my `Gemfile`

```rb
# in test group
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

Then run `bundle install`

Comment: I needed to do this and install the `chromedriver` binary into my path. (I downloaded from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Answer (score 1):

This is because, the libraries are not installed globally

```
sudo gem install --no-user-install selenium-webdriver
```

the above command install the libs inside `ruby-2.3.1@global`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when I used Sublime Text 2 and tried to run using the 'build' button. But the script ran fine when i ran it from the command prompt.

It has more to do with the path assigned to the editor more than anything else. ALthough do a quick a check on your gem list to see if the selenium - webdriver exists there or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when changing laptop.

For me this was the path. In eclipse:
Select 'Window' then 'Preferences' then select 'Ruby' and 'Interpreters'
Ensure the interpreter selected points to your installation .exe of ruby

You could do a search or just browse to the path if you know it.

Once I fixed this I was up and running :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was facing multiple such errors including `cannot load such file — selenium-webdriver (LoadError)`. After installing Ruby dev kit with MSYS2 development tool chain the issue was resolved. Following were the steps followed:

1. Installed Ruby with MSYS2 development tool chain option checked. Be default it is not checked.

[image]

2. Ran all three MSYS2 installations one by one in order

   1 - MSYS2 base installation

   2 - MSYS2 system update (optional)

   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [1,2,3]

3. Checked  Ruby SDK is selected. On Ruby-mine it is at Run->Edit Configuration
4. Installed the gem using: `gem install selenium-webdriver`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using Bundler, so simply adding `require bundler/setup` to the top fixed the problem for me. Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but I just wanted to mention this is probably the *right* answer. It was the solve for me -- the other answers here require you to install the gem globally (rather than as a local dependency to the project). Globals are bad, imo.

Anyways, cheers for this and take the upvote! Hopefully one day it won't be in the negatives