# ocra ruby conversion to exe how to overcome required lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, ocra

I am new to Ruby, and trying to find a solution to convert existing ruby scripts  to exe executables. I choose OCRA to convert ruby script to executbales. I am unable to convert this files to executable. The ocra conversition throwing error , that unable to load required libraries. 
Thanks in advance.

```
===========================================

require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object'

class SubjectSearchPage < CommonElement
  include PageObject

  text_field(:ssnField, :id => "SSN")
  button(:searchBtn, :css => 'button[data-test-id="20180820140732083632904"]')
  h2(:resultsHeaderTitle, :css => 'div[data-test-id="201808231334560745670_header"] h2.header-title')
  elements(:resultRows, :css => '#bodyTbl_right > tbody > tr')
  span(:result, :css => 'span[data-test-id="2016072109335505834280"]')

end

=======================================================

c:\Users\seshaddri\git\pega-functional-tests\selenium-ruby\pages\subject_mgmt>ocra subject_search_page.rb --add-all-core
=== Loading script to check dependencies
C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from c:/Users/seshaddri/git/pega-functional-tests/selenium-ruby/pages/subject_mgmt/subject_search_page.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `load'
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/bin/ocra:23:in `load'
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/bin/ocra:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby selenium cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952022/ruby-selenium-cannot-load-such-file-selenium-webdriver-loaderror)

Comment: Ocra will not convert your code your binaries instead it will pack your project into exe, any one can see your source code. It will unpack your code you run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install the dependencies in your development environment and ocra will package them into the exe for you.

E.g. gem install selenium-webdriver

And then run the build again. Do this for all your projects dependencies.

Comment: Thanks now i am getting different error what to do ?================`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CommonElement (NameError)
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `load'
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/bin/ocra:23:in `load'
        from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/bin/ocra:23:in `<main>'==================

Comment: Did you install the other dependencies also? Like `page-object`?